# how do I put jquery in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been googling for the past hour or so but can't seem to figure out a solution to this problem. I just finished jQuery course from codecademy, and am now working on a project. For some reason my code jquery code will not work

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
$(".storyblocks").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: "+= 20px"
        width: "+= 20px"
    });
});

$(".storyblocks").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: "-= 20px"
        width: "-= 20px"
    });
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project Website</title>
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
```

I added the `$("div").css("border", "3px solid red");` to check if divs have red border, and so far no luck. Some say that I don't need $(document).ready, but I don't understand why not.

Please help?

Comment: are you sure that your path to script.js is correct and the file is loading?  You can use Firebug/Chrome tools to verify that the file is loading.

Comment: Check whether is the file inside a folder for example: js/script.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue with your jQuery not working doesn't have to do with having your jQuery in a separate file, it has to do with a small syntax error: you don't have a comma in between your animate properties, and your animate properties are using incorrect syntax.

Here's your code, but with the necessary commas, and proper syntax for animating properties:

http://jsfiddle.net/4xfAZ/2/

The comma is here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
    $(".storyblocks").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: ($(this).height() + 20) + 'px',
            width: ($(this).width() + 20) + 'px'
        });
    });

    $(".storyblocks").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: ($(this).height() - 20) + 'px',
            width: ($(this).width() - 20) + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

After the height declaration, before the next declaration, you need to separate by commas.

Because your jQuery errored, it didn't do anything, which is why you didn't see the red border :) even though the red border code is separate to the offending code.

HTH

Comment: Why your jsfiddle isn't working? You didn't add the class to the div.

Comment: Oh, I was simply demonstrating how to get valid code. I have updated it so that the entire thing works. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This will set the border :

```
$("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

To check if div have red border with 3px :

```
 if( $("div").css("border") == "3px solid red") {
    console.log('border have red color')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`+=20px` will not work you need to find height of div and then add/subtract `20px`.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
        $(".storyblocks").mouseenter(function(){
            var h = $(this).height()+20;
            var w = $(this).width()+20;
            $(this).animate({
                height: h+"px",//add comma here
                width: w+"px"
            });
        });
        $(".storyblocks").mouseleave(function(){
            var h = $(this).height()-20;
            var w = $(this).width()-20;
            $(this).animate({
                height: h+"px",//add comma here
                width: w+"px"
            });
        });
    });
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/V2R5G/)

Comment: +=20px means what? it should have some default value. isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I want to separate my jquery method in another js file.
so I put Jquery file like as scripts on js file
and put src on main file .

I wrote this code on html file

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="my_jquery_functions.js"></script>
</head>
```

and this code on javasciript file

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#some_id").hide(1500);
});
```